# Swing ComboBox with the choice of "none of the below"

Tags: java, swing

I have a perfectly normal `ArrayList<MyObject>` that I need to edit and pick an object from.

In the application window, I have a `JComboBox` to select the appropriate choice from the list. I'm writing an editor dialog for these objects, which just includes a `JList` of these objects and editor fields. It's easy enough to do; I'll just have a `ListModel` implementation of some kind. Stick the `ArrayList` in, access it through the usual fields. The stuff in the GUI list is 1:1 representation of the stuff in the actual list. Easy.

But the combo box in the main application window is giving me a bit of a headache, because I need a special value. Ideally, the first item in the list should be "(None)", and return a `null`.

Do I just need to write some sort of weird `ComboBoxModel` implementation for this, or is there an easier, already implemented way to do this? I'd definitely imagine this sort of situation has cropped up before.

Comment: using toString() of your object to show the appropriate content in the combo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implementing your own [`ComboBoxModel`](http://ermalaev.spb.ru/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/ComboBoxModel.html) should be quite easy.

Since this solution creates a new `Vector` from your `ArrayList`, changes to `yourArrayList` after creating `Vector` won't be visible in your `JComboBox`. If you need this, then you'll have to implement your own `ComboBoxModel` (see [`DefaultComboBoxModel`](http://ermalaev.spb.ru/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultComboBoxModel.html) implementation).

You would have to do this anyway, since there is no `DefaultComboBoxModel` constructor that takes a `List`.

```
class SpecialComboBoxModel extends DefaultComboBoxModel {
    public final static String NULL_ELEMENT = "<None>";

    public SpecialComboBoxModel(Vector v) {
        super(v);
    }

    @Override
    public int getSize() {
        return super.getSize() + 1;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getElementAt(int index) {
        if( index == 0) {
            return NULL_ELEMENT;
        }
        return super.getElementAt(index - 1);
    }
}


    ArrayList<String> yourArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
    yourArrayList.add("Value1");
    yourArrayList.add("Value2");
    Vector<String> v = new Vector<String>(yourArrayList);
    dropdown.setModel(new SpecialComboBoxModel(v));
```

Comment: Sorry for a really slow reply, but thank you for this. I'll probably need more work on this code to bridge the ArrayList/Vector difference, but your solution was basically that I was looking for and seems to work right now.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use a null-object. For example

```
public class MyObject {
   public static final MyObject NULL_OBJECT = new MyObject();

   ..
}
```

and then in your `ArrayList` just call:

```
arrayList.add(0, MyObject.NULL_OBJECT);
```

You null-object should have all of its properties set to `null` (or to some reasonable defaults), and your `toString()` method (if you are using it), should return "(none)" if all the fields are `null`.

Comment: That's one way to do it, though it will cause some headaches when the ArrayList is saved. I'm using plain ordinary JAXB calls for this. Plus, if the arraylist has a null object as the first item, it will also probably show up in the list editor. This would probably involve a lot of manual additions and removals of the null object to work...

Comment: ah, JAXB comes into the picture. Provide at least some parts of your code so that we can give adequate answers.